# Inherited panel is making controls disappear randomly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a class written that inherits a panel, and enables double buffering to it:

```
Public Class dblBufferPanel
Inherits Panel
Public Sub New()
    'inherit a panel and add double buff to reduce flicker
    'this will be used wherever a panel with gradient or bg img is needed
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    Me.ResizeRedraw = True
End Sub

End Class
```

The problem that I have been facing is that randomly while coding, the controls set within the various panels seem to "vanish" off the panel.  Basically, the panel looks "empty" and there is no way to select the control from form design.  I can however select them in the properties panel, but altering properties of these controls does nothing.  The only solution I have found is that I close VS2010 and restart.  Then, if I did not compile after noticing the controls "vanishing", they reappear upon opening the solution.

This seems to happen with any control, comboboxes, labels, listview, etc.  What would be causing this?

Comment: Are you doing anything in the paint events?  If so, post that code.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your code snippet.  Controls disappear when an exception is raised at design-time.  Don't ignore the message box you get for that.  If you can't sort it out then start another instance of VS and use Tools + Attach to Process to attach it to the first.  Then Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.

Comment: @HansPasst Unfortunately I am getting no errors or exceptions raised either in the designer file or on the design view of the form.  I am able to completely compile and run the application with the controls missing (they are supposed to be visible but they will not show until I completely close VS and restart)

Comment: @LarsTech I am doing nothing with the paint events.